# IBM MobileFirst V6.3 WL.Client.logout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, logout

While calling WL.Client.logout, it asks for two parameters.

1. Realm Name
2. Options

The **Options** parameter does not provide much information if I look into the IBM MobileFirst knowledgecenter documentation. although From one of the sample it shows one of the options be **onSuccess**. what can be the other options for this API. Can there be **onFailure** option as well. If yes, under which circumstance that callback will be executed. As infocenter does not provide much on the options parameter for WL.Client.logout, I wanted to ask this question here.

Answer (score 1):

`WL.Client.logout`'s method signature is: `WL.Client.logout(realm-name,{onSuccess: ..., onFailure});`

So yes, you can use `onFailure` there.
When using logout, its onFailure will be called in cases such as:

- There is no Internet connection
- There is Internet connect but the server is not reachable
- Probably if the realm does not exist (double-check that)

Comment: Ok. If there is custom login module to handle the authentication. and during logout at the server side, there comes some exception. under this scenario, which callback handler will be invoked at the client side - onSuccess or onFailure? As we have a situation where onSuccess is invoked in such a case. Is that the right behavior?

Comment: I'd say onFailure, but it might get swallowed by the onFailure of the custom authentication.

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari, Is the exception handled? At which stage the exception happens or what kind of exception at which method?